# Segmentation fault when using fread() function

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, fread

I have the following struct and array

```
#define PAGE_SIZE 256

typedef struct frame_attribute {
    
    signed char content[PAGE_SIZE];

} frame;

frame pmemory[64];
```

I am trying to read 256 bytes into the content array using fread() in the following way,

```
fread(pmemory[id].content, sizeof(pmemory[id]), PAGE_SIZE, filePointer);
```

and it is giving me a segmentation fault. I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: You may only read `PAGE_SIZE` bytes into that member, not (effectively) `sizeof(pmemory[id]) * PAGE_SIZE` bytes. Also `id` must be in the range `0...63`.

Comment: Also check if `fopen` actually succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to read in the variable `pmemory[id].content` that has the size `PAGE_SIZE` `sizeof(pmemory[id]) * PAGE_SIZE` bytes that in fact is not less than `PAGE_SIZE * PAGE_SIZE` bytes

```
fread(pmemory[id].content, sizeof(pmemory[id]), PAGE_SIZE, filePointer);
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

You need to write at least

```
fread(pmemory[id].content, PAGE_SIZE, 1, filePointer);
```

or

```
fread(pmemory[id].content, sizeof( pmemory[id].content ), 1, filePointer);
```

Answer (score 0):

From man:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

The  function  fread()  reads nmemb items of data,
each size bytes long, from the stream pointed to by stream,
storing them at the location given by ptr.
```

I think the problem is that you are using `sizeof(pmemory[id])`, try changing it to `sizeof(signed char)`.

You want to read **PAGE_SIZE** items of data to save in a **signed char** array, so the items must be of **signed char** size.